# How to set Microsoft Excel chart OLE object chart type

Tags: excel, charts, powerbuilder

How to set chart type of Microsoft Excel chart OLE object in PowerBuilder?

I want to set chart type of Excel chart dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Insert control OLE]

[image: Insert Object Microsoft excel chart]

You can do something  like this....

Comment: This is how you can add ole object.My question was how to ser charttype after adding the chart through powerbuilder